# How to fade animate background images (full size)

Tags: javascript, css, animation, jquery-animate, background-image

I'm looking for a script ! I want to do like the footer of this website ( animation between the background images where it's written '' Don't miss any update '')  : https://getgoldee.com/

Does anyone know a similar script or is able to get it from this website ?

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: view-source:https://getgoldee.com/

Comment: Obviously I did right click, but I can't find the script in question... 
It's a it's a bit complicated for me!

Comment: At line 1122 and downwards...

Ctrl + F is also a good shortcut after view source :)

Comment: It just fades in-out three images like : https://getgoldee.com/img/footer-bg1.png

Comment: It's just fade in-out ? Ok, i will try ! I know where are the script, but not the one who did this ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it with a couple of jQ lines:

```js
var $bg = $('#bg'),
    $bgDIV = $('div', $bg), // Cache  your elements
    n = $bgDIV.length,      // count them (used to loop with % reminder)
    c = 0;                  //  counter

(function loopBG(){ 
  $bgDIV.eq(++c%n).hide().appendTo($bg).fadeTo(3000,1, loopBG);
}());   // start fade animation
```

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}

body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

#bg{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#bg:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  z-index:1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:url(//i.stack.imgur.com/D0AZ1.png);
}
#bg > div{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: none 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
#bg > #one{   background-image: url('//i.stack.imgur.com/T3U9b.png'); }
#bg > #two{   background-image: url('//i.stack.imgur.com/UKeA2.png'); }
#bg > #three{ background-image: url('//i.stack.imgur.com/hrArW.png'); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Also don't forget to wrap your jQuery code in `document.ready` function like `jQuery(function($){  /*code here*/  });`

Answer (score 0):

If you analize its sources, the code handling this animation is in the file:

https://getgoldee.com/js/main.js

The code is quite simple:

```
var footerBgContainer = $('.footer-bgs');

function setFooterBackground(bgNumber) {
    var prev = footerBgContainer.find('.bg');

    setTimeout(function () {
        prev.remove();
    }, 4100);

    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className += 'bg bg' + bgNumber;

    footerBgContainer.append(el);

    setTimeout(function () {
        el.className += ' show';
    }, 20);
}

function footerBgRotating(interval) {
    var current = 1;

    setInterval(function () {
        setFooterBackground((current % 3) + 1);
        current++;
    }, interval);
}

footerBgRotating(4000);
```

As you can see, it changes CSS class with a timeout function.

Styles are: (animation is in CSS)

```
footer .bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 4s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 4s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 4s linear;
    transition: opacity 4s linear
}

footer .bg.show {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 4s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 4s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 4s linear;
    transition: opacity 4s linear
}

footer .bg.bg1 {
    background: url("../img/footer-bg1.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover
}

footer .bg.bg2 {
    background: url("../img/footer-bg2.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover
}

footer .bg.bg3 {
    background: url("../img/footer-bg3.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But i have an error and don't know why ! ReferenceError: $ is not defined from the : var footerBgContainer = $('.footer-bgs');

Comment: $ is jQuery. You need jQuery library to run the code.